# Django with MySQL migration is not working

Tags: mysql, django

I have created a sample application by using Python V3.6 and Django 2.1 and I am using MySQL for the database. I have successfully integrated MySQL after a long struggle but now when I try to create a SuperUser for my application it is throwing an error

```
(django_dev) C:\Users\******\Desktop\django_projects\shield>python manage.py mig
rate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, server_status, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying server_status.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'shield_dev.django_content_typ
e' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 226, in handle
    self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps,
plan=plan,
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\core\management\sql.py", line 51, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 59, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 51, in get_for_model
    ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\models\query.py", line 393, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\models\query.py", line 1183, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=
self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1061, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._e
xecute)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dja
ngo\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MyS
QLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'shield_dev.django_content_type'
 doesn't exist")

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
```

Everything is working fine if I were using the default database SqLite3, but when I tried with MySQL I am getting the bug.

Here my setting.py for your references.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'polls',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'shield_dev',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '******',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the migrations folder in the  app folder and re-run the makemigrations command in the terminal. Also make sure that the SQL connection parameters are correct

Comment: Please show the `server_status.0001_initial` migration that is causing the error.

Comment: @KeshavGarg I deleted migration folder inside my application folder and re-run the makemigration command but still, I am getting an error - Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:

Comment: @Alasdair sorry deleted my migration folder. Is there any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: @SethuKarthik what is the error you're getting now?

Comment: @dirkgroten `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'shield_dev.django_content_type'
 doesn't exist")` this is what I am getting. Please let me know I were not clear I will share the entire error log for me.

Comment: You should think very carefully before deleting migrations. If the database and migrations get out of sync it can be very difficult to resolve the issue. In this case, it sounds like you don't have any important data in the database yet so I would drop the database, create new migrations, then migrate. If this doesn't work, then you'll get a *different* error message, so you have to show the full traceback of the new error.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes you are correct I don't have anything in my DB, I have created my DB from MySQL admin and connected to my Django application and try to migrate with that DB this is what I did exactly.

Comment: As I said: If this doesn't work, then you'll get a different error message, so you have to show the full traceback of the new error. Your current `settings.py` does not contain `'server_status'`, so the error message will not mention `server_status.0001_initial`.

Comment: And show us the code of the migration file that fails. When you see a line like `Applying server_status.0001_initial... OK` it means there is a file `0001_initial.py` in your `server_status` app migrations. Now, you should more likely see something like `Applying polls.0001_initial... ERROR` or something like that.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks it is working now but still now I am not clear why I was not working and why it is working now :-(

Comment: You never showed the `server_status.0001_initial` migration that was causing the error, so we can't tell what the problem was either.

Comment: @Alasdair I didn't find any server_status.0001_initial in my project.

Comment: It would be in the `server_status/migrations` folder. You said you deleted it.

Comment: Yes, I deleted but, I have done a new migration so, it was supposed to re-generated right?

Comment: @Alasdair All the issues resolved and it is working fine now but, why I still see this message in my log `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in
 that same thread. The object was created in thread id 10048 and this is thread i
d 4292'

Comment: *I have done a new migration so, it was supposed to re-generated right?* You can create new migrations for the `server_status` app by adding it to `INSTALLED_APPS` then running `manage.py makemigrations server_status`. The new migration file might be different from the original, so might not give the same error.

Comment: I can't help with the sqlite error. It doesn't seem related to the original error, so is off topic for this question.